# Can multiple python scripts communicate with a single serial port?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

I have several arduino and one raspberry pi connected together via rs485

The raspberry pi has a webserver that allows the direct query to the rs485 line and also allows sheduling of automatic queries, managed by crontab, which answers are saved in mysql DB.

Each crontab job executes the same python script followed by a string to be sent through the serial line

The problem:

- crontab executes some commands simultaneously and the serial data overlap
- an independent query could interfere with the planned queries

Before opening the serial I tried to check if USB0 port "is_open" but it seems that the answer refers only to the serial instance running in current python script

running in python:

```
ser = serial.Serial(serPath,38400,timeout=1.0)
```

and then running this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser.baudrate = 38400
ser.timeout = 1.0
print(ser.is_open)
# always returns False
ser.open()
print(ser.is_open)
# always returns True
```

If I execute

```
print(ser)
```

I can see that the serial id is different each time I run

```
ser = serial.Serial()
```

Is there a way to know if the serial USB0 is free or busy?

As an alternative is there a way with a python script to save a flag, a variable or something that an independent script can read and understand whether or not to use the serial port?

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest as these are all your scripts that you update them to `flock` the serial port device:

```
import fcntl
s = open('/dev/ttyUSB0')
# you have a choice of either blocking or not
fcntl.flock(s, fcntl.LOCK_EX) 
# blocks
fcntl.flock(s, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB) 
# raises IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

If each of scripts flock the device before attempting to use it then no more than one of them can be using the device at a time as the second will block or with `LOCK_NB` will fail to lock the file.

The lock is released when the file is closed.

Note that this is an advisory lock it doesn't prevent anyone that does not attempt to flock the device from using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use this, paired with some other logic, if I correctly interpreted your problem:

```
import os

pids = os.system('fuser /dev/ttyUSB0')
```

Essentially what this does is call a Linux command which returns the pids of processes using a given resource. Therefore, for your problem, you can just check to see if there are no other programs using the usb device. It `fuser` is not exactly fast, but it should get the job done.

Comment: I tried adding while os.system('fuser /dev/ttyUSB0') !=256: time.sleep(1)  before ser.open() . Since the scripts start at the same time, python execution continues beyond the while causing the strings to overlap on the serial line. I do not know why 256 but it is what os.system('fuser /dev/ttyUSB0') returns when the serial is not used by any process